# How to get all unsuspended users from the database, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new in Laravel, and I have been assigned a task to send a notification only to active users. The active state is determined by a column in the DB called `suspended` which is a tinyint for a boolean value.

I wrote this call:

```
//Code here
$users = $asset->campaign->users();

$eagerly_users = $users
             ->where('suspended', false)
             ->with('preferences')
             ->get();
```

but for some reason it is not returning the correct users.

Comment: try using '0' and '1' instead false

Comment: @RolandStarke 0 worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
   while(mysqli_fetch_array($row)) {
       echo $row['user']
   }
```

note this works after you have queried the table to select only rows with content in the suspended column